# How to switch to Iframe in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am finding difficult to enter the user name and password  present on the iframe  which gets popped up when we click on the signin link.

Can somebody help me on this.

Site link given below

link : http://cashkaro.iamsavings.co.uk/

With Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please find the answer below 

public void login_normally() {
        
        navigate_to_url(prop.getProperty("url_prod_Locale"));
        // Parent window
        String parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println("Parent windiow :" + parent_window);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("singin_link"))).click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 7);
          String iframe_xpath = prop.getProperty("iframe_com_xpath");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By
                .xpath(iframe_xpath)));

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("email_id_InSignIn")))
                .sendKeys(prop.getProperty("user_email_id_signIn"));
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty("password_InSign")))
                .sendKeys(prop.getProperty("pwd_signIn"));

        boolean check_box_flag = driver.findElement(
                By.xpath(prop.getProperty("Keep_me_signed_in"))).isSelected();
        System.out.println("check_box_flag" + check_box_flag);

        if (check_box_flag == false) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("Keep_me_signed_in")))
                    .click();
        }

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("sign_button_signIn")))
                .click();
 //=================================================================================
/*      String login_mesg_error = driver.findElement(
                By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty("loginerror"))).getText();
        System.out.println(" login Error : " + login_mesg_error);
        
            
        if (login_mesg_error.length()<0 ) {
            System.out.println("Sucessfully Loggedin");
            Assert.assertTrue(true, "Sucessfull Login");
            APPLICATION_LOG.debug(login_mesg_error);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Login Failed");
            Assert.assertTrue(false, login_mesg_error);
            APPLICATION_LOG.debug(login_mesg_error);
        }*/
        
//==============================================================================
        String login_mesg_error=" ";
        List<WebElement> li=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(prop.getProperty("logout_button_css")));
        System.out.println(" list size :" +li.size());
                
        if(li.size()>0)
        {
            System.out.println("Sucessfully Loggedin");
            Assert.assertTrue(true, "Sucessfull Login");
            APPLICATION_LOG.debug("Sucessfull Login");
        } else {
            login_mesg_error = driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath(prop.getProperty("login_error_mesg"))).getText();
            System.out.println(" login Error : " + login_mesg_error);
            System.out.println("Login Failed");
            Assert.assertTrue(false, "Login failed - Incorrect username or password");
            APPLICATION_LOG.debug(login_mesg_error + "Login failed");
        }
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a predefined method exists in `Selenium` which you can use to switch to a `Frame` or an `IFrame`.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

There are 3 overloaded methods which you can use to switch to a frame.

```
1. driver.switchTo().frame(String frameId);
2. driver.switchTo().frame(int frameNumber);
3. driver.switchTo().frame(WebElement frame);
```

You can either of the above 3 methods to switch on a frame.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

For the switch to an iframe, you can use:

```
 public void switchToFrame(WebElement element) {
        getDriver().switchTo().frame(element);
    }
```

or

```
wati.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By locator)

wati.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(WebElement element)
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with iframe you must switch from your **current page** to **iframe.**
Try the below code and let me know your result.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://cashkaro.iamsavings.co.uk/");

String linkText = "SIGN IN";

WebElement eventElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText(linkText)));        

eventElement.click();

WebElement frame = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/div[14]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/iframe")));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);

driver.findElement(By.id("uname")).sendKeys("username@domain.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("uname")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB); 
driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("enteryourpassword"); 
driver.findElement(By.id("sign_in")).click();
```

*Use your valid login credentials to sign in.*