# Why can't I get Selenium to recognize this particular span element?

Tags: selenium, xpath

Please see this screenshot of the site http://speedtest.shaw.ca/ along with the HTML:

[image]

I'm trying to use Selenium to automate pushing the "Go" button, but I need to wait until the "Finding Optimal Server" status is gone. Is there any reason why the following Selenium code refuses to recognize the `span`?

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,  10);

driver.get("http://speedtest.shaw.ca/");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Finding Optimal Server')]")));
```

Since the element I'm waiting for is `<span>Finding Optimal Server...</span>`, it seems to be the right xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element which you're trying to access is inside an iframe.

Therefore, you need to switch to the iframe before you will be able to interact with the inner elements.

See related question of how to switch iframes: [How to switch to Iframe in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687149/how-to-switch-to-iframe-in-selenium)