# Click the Button and get the size of table in Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to learn selenium to find elements and  I could not clicking the "Edit"buttons and Im trying the get the size of the rows of the table.

Here is my code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
String baseUrl = "https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/PopupEditing/Angular/Light/";
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
List<WebElement> we = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Edit")); System.out.println(we.size());
we.get(1).click();
```

Here is the link that I am working:
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/PopupEditing/Angular/Light/
[image]

Comment: I think its the reason cause its in an other iframe, you should change iframe after your findby xpath will works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687149/how-to-switch-to-iframe-in-selenium

Comment: Please don't post links and screenshots. Copy the relevant code into your question, and format it accordingly. This will greatly increase the chance for you to get help.

Comment: @ThomasHirsch you are right ..I added my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/PopupEditing/Angular/Light/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
WebElement frame = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("demoFrame"))));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[class=\"dx-link dx-link-edit\"]"))).click();
```

Use webdriver wait and switchTo frame, you have to switch to iframe first to interacte elements inside the iframe.

once you finish , if you want to interact with elements outside iframe then you have to switch out of it first.

```
 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
 //rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

The element is present inside an `iframe` and you need to switch `iframe` first and then you will be able to interact with element.

To overcome synchronization issue you need to induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()` and following locator.

To get the link details induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and following locator.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
String baseUrl = "https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/PopupEditing/Angular/Light/";
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.manage().window().maximize();        
new WebDiverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("demoFrame")));
List<WebElement> we =new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.linkText("Edit")));
System.out.println(we.size());
we.get(1).click();
```